# how to access webservice deployed in remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Please help me , how to add web service which is deployed in  remote server. externally i unable to access that service..in that remote server only that service will run but we don't have Ms.net Environment to add service to my application in that server.

So please guide me how to add that web service to my application ,not accessig externally that service URl, internally Executing that URl.
How can i add that service to my application on my developer PC ?

Comment: Your solution will need to be deployed internally if you want it to access a web-service which is only accessible from your internal network. If you want this to be accessible from outside, you will need to expose your web service over the internet.

Comment: can u please clarify me..with out doing Add web reference process can't we access that web service methods.?i mean i need to Fetch & update the records using that service.thing is if IP address of the Web service Url changes every time i need to deploy the application it's bit tough.So can't we do  by using Web.config ? please guide me..it's very tough time for me. plss...

Answer (score 1):

To add a web reference you need to have access to the WSDL file.

You need to do this in 2 steps:

- First add a web reference to your project based on the WSDL
- Then change the URL of the web reference to match the address of the external service

Comment: hi..Without doing add reference can't we use the Web service..?if any chance please guide me..my web service is only accessible at client server only.So how can i add that service at my devlpment machine and how to add that service..

Answer (score 0):

You can move service URL to web config please refer here.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1268077/2388602.aspx

But if your IP address changes too often (Dynamic IP) I think better your remote network configuration should be changed to have some sort of redirection to your Dynamic IP via a Static IP in your outside network so you can give that Static IP as service URL.

So you don't have to change the web config even too often.

Anyway you Should get advice from a network administrator.